# Unwanted print repetition in Java loop

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, printing

This method is meant to print the amount of coins in each unique pile once, yet although the values are printed correctly, it prints too many times (e.g. it will print the number of coins for x pile, then for y pile, then for z pile, then for x pile again, then for y pile again, etc.)

How should I fix this?

```
public static int CoinsperPile (int[][] arr)
{
    int n = 0;
    int total = 0;
    for (int row = 1; row < arr.length; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 1; col < arr[0].length; col++)
        {
            if (arr[row][col] == 1)
            {
                n = n + arr[0][col];
            }
        }
        total = total + n;
        System.out.println("There are " + n + " coins in pile " + row );
        n = 0;
    }
    return total;
}
```

Comment: The code you posted prints once for each row. You must be calling the method multiple times.

Comment: It looks like your pile is represented by a "1" for each coin. If that's true, then the statement `n = n + arr[0][col]` should instead be simply `++n` . Also, your earlier reference to `arr[0].length` should probably be `arr[row].length`. If you've got a rectangular array, it won't matter, but it's safer in general.

Comment: Can you show what it is printing?

Comment: Never mind, I finally figured out that the problem was somewhere else in my code. Thanks all for your help though! Since I'm really new to programming, I learned a lot.